# Font Awesome 5 treatment of embedded icons in form input fields - Formatting is off vs V4.7

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, font-awesome-5

I have the following html/php code in a laravel blade template that renders a font awesome 4.7 input field:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    {!! Form::text('locName', old('locName'),
        $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control has-feedback-left', 'maxlength' => '50', 'id'=>'locName', 'placeholder'=>'Location Name', 'required')) !!}
    <span class="fa fa-building form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

which renders as follows:

[image: input tag with embedded font-awesome 4.7 icon]

I'm in the process of upgrading my usage of FA 4.7 to 5Pro and when I modify this in the following way (code below) the formatting isn't quite the same.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    {!! Form::text('locName', old('locName'),
        $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control has-feedback-left', 'maxlength' => '50', 'id'=>'locName', 'placeholder'=>'Location Name', 'required')) !!}
    <span class="far fa-building fa-fw form-control-feedback fa-pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

The above PHP as HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control has-feedback-left" maxlength="50" id="locName" placeholder="Location Name" required name="locName" type="text">
    <span class="far fa-building fa-fw form-control-feedback fa-pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

[image: input tag with fontawesome 5.0]

I haven't been able to find a corresponding 5.0 example sheet that details this and do not believe any of the existing FA(5) questions cover it either.

And yes, both the css and js pro links are included.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the fontawesome css? I got the icon to show using 5.0

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    {!! Form::text('locName', old('locName'),
        $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control has-feedback-left', 'maxlength' => '50', 'id'=>'locName', 'placeholder'=>'Location Name', 'required')) !!}
    <span class="far fa-building fa-fw form-control-feedback fa-pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The css file hadn't been included.  After including it, the output hasn't changed and it still looks like the 2nd image.